# Android 4.1.2 Settings Subcategory missing

Tags: factory-reset, accounts

I have a japanese phone (Fujitsu F-02e) and recently I did a factory reset. After the factory reset I found out that the Accounts subcategory is missing. Does anyone have any idea how to get it back? Before the factory reset the subcategory was there. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had a Xposed module named AccountSectionRemover active. My fault!